# App Rejection from AppStore But Complete working in all devices

Tags: ios, ipv6, appstore-approval

I had uploaded this app for 3 times and I am getting rejection They write like your app is not IPV6 supportive and all kind of stuff like it is crashing. I've tried all possible ways like 
1> I've checked it in IPV6. As suggested by Apple.
2> I've done all the changes regarding to IPV6.

```
Incident Identifier: FBD50FB2-086A-4ED0-8B50-7C148A81B9F4
CrashReporter Key:   65143e6b5800c3b20bdf8217cfae74c400052cfe
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             livephotoToGift [699]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E85F4A6-C382-405F-A048-66A7644B495A/livephotoToGift.app/livephotoToGift
Version:             1.2 (1.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-09-05 08:51:55.55 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-09-05 08:51:37.37 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.5 (13G36)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010013618c
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   livephotoToGift                 0x000000010013618c 0x1000e0000 + 352652
1   Regift                          0x000000010056bbcc 0x100564000 + 31692
2   livephotoToGift                 0x00000001001353ac 0x1000e0000 + 349100
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180c8d4bc 0x180c8c000 + 5308
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180c8d47c 0x180c8c000 + 5244
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180c92b84 0x180c8c000 + 27524
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811f8d50 0x181118000 + 920912
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811f6bb8 0x181118000 + 912312
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181120c50 0x181118000 + 35920
9   GraphicsServices                0x0000000182a08088 0x1829fc000 + 49288
10  UIKit                           0x0000000186406088 0x186388000 + 516232
11  livephotoToGift                 0x0000000100102db8 0x1000e0000 + 142776
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000180cbe8b8 0x180cbc000 + 10424

Activity ID:             0x0000000000006ab1
Activity Name:           send control actions
Activity Image Path:     /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
Activity Image UUID:     BC9398E0-3D59-3B3F-B4B6-6794602F9602
Activity Offset:         0x00034708
Activity Running Time:   0.287288 sec



Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ddcb48 0x180dc0000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5530 0x180ea4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5020 0x180ea4000 + 4128

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ddd4d8 0x180dc0000 + 120024
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180ca07d8 0x180c8c000 + 83928
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180c8f648 0x180c8c000 + 13896

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ddcb48 0x180dc0000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5530 0x180ea4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5020 0x180ea4000 + 4128

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ddcb48 0x180dc0000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5530 0x180ea4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5020 0x180ea4000 + 4128

Thread 5 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180dc0fd8 0x180dc0000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180dc0e54 0x180dc0000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811f8c60 0x181118000 + 920672
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811f6964 0x181118000 + 911716
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181120c50 0x181118000 + 35920
5   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x00000001878959e0 0x187850000 + 285152
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x000000018786a75c 0x187850000 + 108380
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7b28 0x180ea4000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7a8c 0x180ea4000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5028 0x180ea4000 + 4136

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ddcb48 0x180dc0000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5530 0x180ea4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5020 0x180ea4000 + 4128

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180dc0fd8 0x180dc0000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180dc0e54 0x180dc0000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811f8c60 0x181118000 + 920672
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811f6964 0x181118000 + 911716
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181120c50 0x181118000 + 35920
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001818a1bcc 0x1817f4000 + 711628
6   Foundation                      0x0000000181c17e4c 0x181b24000 + 998988
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7b28 0x180ea4000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7a8c 0x180ea4000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5028 0x180ea4000 + 4136

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ddc344 0x180dc0000 + 115524
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811ff1c8 0x181118000 + 946632
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7b28 0x180ea4000 + 15144
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7a8c 0x180ea4000 + 14988
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5028 0x180ea4000 + 4136

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ddcb48 0x180dc0000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5530 0x180ea4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5020 0x180ea4000 + 4128

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ddcb48 0x180dc0000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5530 0x180ea4000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5020 0x180ea4000 + 4128

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180dc0fd8 0x180dc0000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180dc0e54 0x180dc0000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811f8c60 0x181118000 + 920672
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811f6964 0x181118000 + 911716
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181120c50 0x181118000 + 35920
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018116e3a4 0x181118000 + 353188
6   CoreMotion                      0x00000001870eb41c 0x187098000 + 341020
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7b28 0x180ea4000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7a8c 0x180ea4000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5028 0x180ea4000 + 4136

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ddc41c 0x180dc0000 + 115740
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000180cf922c 0x180cec000 + 53804
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001808713b4 0x18082c000 + 283572
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184e3e768 0x1848b8000 + 5793640
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184e3e340 0x1848b8000 + 5792576
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184e40ad8 0x1848b8000 + 5802712
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184e40a68 0x1848b8000 + 5802600
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7b28 0x180ea4000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7a8c 0x180ea4000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5028 0x180ea4000 + 4136

Thread 13 name:  WebThread
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180dc0fd8 0x180dc0000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180dc0e54 0x180dc0000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811f8c60 0x181118000 + 920672
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811f6964 0x181118000 + 911716
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181120c50 0x181118000 + 35920
5   WebCore                         0x000000018510a108 0x185094000 + 483592
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7b28 0x180ea4000 + 15144
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7a8c 0x180ea4000 + 14988
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5028 0x180ea4000 + 4136

Thread 14 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180dc1014 0x180dc0000 + 4116
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180c9e3e8 0x180c8c000 + 74728
2   MediaToolbox                    0x00000001871cd330 0x1871c8000 + 21296
3   CoreMedia                       0x00000001835faccc 0x1835b8000 + 273612
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7b28 0x180ea4000 + 15144
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7a8c 0x180ea4000 + 14988
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5028 0x180ea4000 + 4136

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180dc102c 0x180dc0000 + 4140
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180c9e394 0x180c8c000 + 74644
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180c9d954 0x180c8c000 + 72020
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7b28 0x180ea4000 + 15144
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7a8c 0x180ea4000 + 14988
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5028 0x180ea4000 + 4136

Thread 16 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ddbf24 0x180dc0000 + 114468
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea6ce8 0x180ea4000 + 11496
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018083342c 0x18082c000 + 29740
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184bf0d5c 0x1848b8000 + 3378524
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184bf0df4 0x1848b8000 + 3378676
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001848c6614 0x1848b8000 + 58900
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001848c6524 0x1848b8000 + 58660
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7b28 0x180ea4000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7a8c 0x180ea4000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5028 0x180ea4000 + 4136

Thread 17 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ddbf24 0x180dc0000 + 114468
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea6ce8 0x180ea4000 + 11496
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018083342c 0x18082c000 + 29740
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184bf0d5c 0x1848b8000 + 3378524
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000184bf0df4 0x1848b8000 + 3378676
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001848c6614 0x1848b8000 + 58900
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001848c6524 0x1848b8000 + 58660
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7b28 0x180ea4000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7a8c 0x180ea4000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5028 0x180ea4000 + 4136

Thread 18 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180dc0fd8 0x180dc0000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180dc0e54 0x180dc0000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811f8c60 0x181118000 + 920672
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811f6964 0x181118000 + 911716
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181120c50 0x181118000 + 35920
5   WebCore                         0x0000000185137950 0x185094000 + 670032
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001848c6614 0x1848b8000 + 58900
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001848c6524 0x1848b8000 + 58660
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7b28 0x180ea4000 + 15144
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7a8c 0x180ea4000 + 14988
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5028 0x180ea4000 + 4136

Thread 19 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ddbf24 0x180dc0000 + 114468
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea6ce8 0x180ea4000 + 11496
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001848c9b80 0x1848b8000 + 72576
3   WebKitLegacy                    0x00000001861094a4 0x18609c000 + 447652
4   WebKitLegacy                    0x0000000186108b60 0x18609c000 + 445280
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001848c6614 0x1848b8000 + 58900
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001848c6524 0x1848b8000 + 58660
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7b28 0x180ea4000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea7a8c 0x180ea4000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ea5028 0x180ea4000 + 4136

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000180e9e8f4   x2: 0x0000000159ba3650   x3: 0x0000000000000005
    x4: 0x000000016fd1e0d8   x5: 0x000000016fd1e5f0   x6: 0x000000000000000a   x7: 0x000000016fd1e858
    x8: 0x0000000100cc9408   x9: 0x0000000000004000  x10: 0x0000000159ba4000  x11: 0x0000000000003fff
   x12: 0x0000000159ba0000  x13: 0x0000000000003fff  x14: 0xffffffffffffc000  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x0000000180e08168  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000015812fe00
   x20: 0x000000010031f680  x21: 0x0000000159ba28b0  x22: 0x0000000100827a66  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x00000001008697f8
   x28: 0x0000000100a90f80  fp: 0x000000016fd1ea30   lr: 0x00000001001358fc
    sp: 0x000000016fd1e900   pc: 0x000000010013618c cpsr: 0x80000000
```

I don't know Where they are finding problem. If anybody knows please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible crash when `send control actions`. Check all action in your app and test it on real devices, some times simulator doesn't incur crash.

Comment: what is send control actions??

Comment: Check your crash log, refer 2nd paragraph in log. you will get idea.

Comment: I checked but i am unable to understand this. What it is saying. Can you please help in understanding this??

Comment: Possibly its some button action or action method causing crash.

Comment: It' s the crash report sent by Apple. I check this app several time in diff device and simulator but it never crash!!!!!. What should be there??

Comment: is your app written in swift, then its due to nil value assignment or type conversion.

Comment: yes . My App is in swift.

Comment: Check you are not assigning nil value at runtime, might be your API or any runtime generated data with nil value causing crash.

Comment: To understand crash load you can refer Apple Documentation on [Understanding and Analyzing iOS Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Comment: Let's see .. Hope for the best..

Comment: But I am Testing on My device It has zero crash.. And I am Also not getting any crash on IPV6 environment I've tested it my self. If I dont find any crashes why Appstore REjecting It. It's very embarrassing and frustrating. I am tired with those AppStore Guys.

Comment: You can either call to Apple Support and discuss for the issue or you can ask for detailed reason in Resolution centre on iTunes connect. It will definitely help you.

Comment: They are only giving us Crash Reports and saying that check it on IPV6. Ok. I am trying again.

Comment: You can ask them in specific, that i have tried this methods to check IPV6 compatibility. Verify with them whether you have done right or wrong, better you go on a call with them. Make sure you are not using IP address to invoke any of the API in your app.

Comment: I haven't use any IP address to invoke an API. Ok Let us call them and I will update you about the states. Anyways Thanks buddy.